# How to import existing stored procedure in Entity Framework code-first from entity data wizard?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, entity-framework-6

Today I'm simulating code first with an existing database approach. But on Entity Data Model Wizard in VS 2017 -> Import selected stored procedures an functions into the entity model check box is disabled. Please see attached screenshot:

[Entity Data Model Wizard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGXz4.png).

So how do I enable that option?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to import the procedures.

Use of exisitng store procedures(InsertStudent,UpdateStudent) are shown in code sample. Just need to override `OnModelCreating` method and map store procedures with entities.

Kindly refer to this page http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework6/code-first-insert-update-delete-stored-procedure-mapping.aspx for detailed information.

```
public class SchoolContext: DbContext 
{
   protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   {

     modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
        .MapToStoredProcedures(p => p.Insert(sp => sp.HasName("InsertStudent").Parameter(pm => pm.StudentName, "name").Result(rs => rs.StudentId, "Id"))
            .Update(sp => sp.HasName("UpdateStudent").Parameter(pm => pm.StudentName, "name"))
            .Delete(sp => sp.HasName("DeleteStudent").Parameter(pm => pm.StudentId, "Id"))
        );
   }
}
```

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: @marc_s, Yes, i understand, i do not need to import stored procedures. But what about the stored procedures that are already presented in my database?. Is that means, am i no longer gonna use them?

Comment: Hi @narendras14, Have you read the code given in answer? It's using exisitng store procedures(InsertStudent,UpdateStudent). You need to override `OnModelCreating` method and map store procedures with entities.